# Finiteness and Lower Semi-Continuity of an Functional.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, lipschitz-functions, semicontinuous-functions

Assume I have a probability density $\rho$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with finite second moment

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\|x\|^2\rho(x) dx<C. $$

I'm now interested in the following functional

$$ F(\rho):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) \rho(x)dx, $$

for some $f\in C(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which is bounded from below : $f(x)\geq c$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Two questions, under what conditions on $f$ do we need for

- 1. $F$ finite?
- 2. $F$ lower semi-continuous?

Is $f$ Lipschitz enough or Im guessing it WILL depend on $\rho$?

EDIT : maybe Theorem $2.38$ of Functions of bounded variation and free discontinuity problems by Luigi Ambrosio could help?

Comment: You want $F$ to be a functional on the space of probabilty densities with finite second moment? What topology do you give this space in order to speak about lower semi continuous or Lipschitz?

Comment: yes $F$ a function on probability densities with finite second moments and the topology of weak convergence.

Comment: @s.harp and by Lipschitz I mean $f$ is Lipschitz w.r.t the standard topology.

Comment: So you include these measures into the space of radon measures of finite variation, the weak topology is then understood wrt the dual of that space. But this weak topology is locally convex and not metric or normed - I still don't how you define Lipschitz.

Comment: @s.harp $f$ Lipschitz, $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: oh.... Lipschitz as a condition on $f$ not as a conclusion for $F$, ok gotcha

Answer (score 0):

For $F$ to be finite you need that $\frac{f(x)}{\|x\|^2+1}$ is bounded.

This is clearly sufficient.

Lets check that it is necessary:

> Suppose you have a sequence $x_n$ with $\frac{f(x_n)}{\|x_n\|^2+1}≥ 4^n$. By continuity of $f$ these $x_n$ will eventually escape every compactum, so you may assume $\|x_n- x_m\|>1$ for $n\neq m$ and $\|x_n\|>1$ for all $n$. Around each $x_n$ you have a ball on which $f(x)≥4^n\|x_n\|^2$ holds, wlog this ball has radius $<1$ so that all these balls around $x_n$ are disjoint.
>
> On a given such ball look at some bump-function $\rho_n$ supported on the ball so that $\int \rho_n = \frac{2^{-n}}{\|x_n\|^2+1}$. It is clear that $\rho:=\sum_n \rho_n$ remains smooth, positive and
> $$\int \rho<\infty, \quad \int\|x\|^2\rho ≤\sum_n 2^{-n}=1$$
> By rescaling $\rho$ you may make it into a probability measure, it is then of the class you are considering. Now
> $$F(\rho) =\sum_n \int f\, \rho_n ≥\sum_n 4^n\|x_n\|^2\int \rho_n = \sum_n 2^n \frac{\|x_n\|^2}{\|x_n\|^2+1}=\infty$$

Note that if $f$ is Lipschitz this condition is satisfied.

Now about lower-semi-continuity:

> Fix some $\rho$ and consider a net $\rho_\alpha\to\rho$ weakly. Let $\psi_n$ be the characteristic function of the ball of radius $n$. By weak convergence you've got $\int \psi_n\rho_\alpha \to \int\psi_n \rho$ as $\alpha\to\infty$. But you've also got that
> $$\int \psi_n \rho\to 1$$
> as $n\to\infty$. This means that for every $\epsilon$ you've got an $n(\epsilon)$ so that the mass of $\rho$ outside of the  ball of radius $n$ is smaller than $\epsilon$. Additionally the two equations mean you've got an $A(\epsilon)$ so that for all $\alpha>A$ the mass of $\rho_\alpha$ outside of the ball of radius $n(\epsilon)$ is smaller than $2\epsilon$.
>
> Now $f\cdot \psi_n$ is bounded and hence
> $$\int f \psi_n\, \rho_\alpha\to \int f\psi_n \,\rho$$
> Make use of this, for $n=n(\epsilon)$ and $\alpha ≥ A(\epsilon)$ you've got:
> $$\int f \rho_\alpha = \int f \psi_n\,\rho_\alpha + \int f(1-\psi_n)\rho_\alpha ≥ \int f \psi_n \rho_\alpha + 2c \epsilon$$
> the term on the right converges, as $\alpha\to\infty$, towards
> $$\int f\psi_n\, \rho+ 2c\epsilon$$
> where $\epsilon$ is as small as you please although $n$ will get larger with smaller $\epsilon$. But as $n$ goes to infinity the integral $\int f\psi_n\,\rho$ converges to $\int f\rho$ (here you again use that $f$ is bounded below and something like Beppo-Levi).
>
> All these words amount to:
> $$\limsup_\alpha \int f\,\rho_\alpha ≥ \int f\rho$$

So $F$ is lower semi-continuous if $f$ is bounded below (finiteness not necessary).